# Data Studio Community Connector error: The number of columns in the data does not match the number in the schema

Tags: looker-studio

I'm writing a Connector following the recommended [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#13) and facing am issue, that is already discussed on [another question] but it didn't solve my case.

I'm getting the `Data Studio Community Connector error: The number of columns in the data does not match the number in the schema.` message even thinking that everything is ok.

I double-checked the requested fields and returned just the asked ones. It asked for 7 number fields that were returned like expected.

I appreciate any help.

My `getData()` method:

```
function getData(request) {
   try {
     console.log("getData - request", request);

     // Create schema for requested fields
     var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
       return field.name;
     });
     var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(requestedFieldIds);

     // Fetch and parse data from API
     var url = [
       'https://api.hubstaff.com',
       '/v2/organizations/',
       request.organizationId,
       '/activities/daily',
       '?date[start]=2019-12-19&date[stop]=2019-12-26'
     ];

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.join(''));    
     var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);   
     var rows = responseToRows(requestedFields, parsedResponse);

     console.log("getData - rows", rows);

     return {
       schema: requestedFields.build(),
       rows: rows
     };

  } catch (e) { 
    e = (typeof e === 'string') ? new Error(e) : e;
    Logger.log("Catch", e);
    console.log("Catch", e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

The `"getData - request"` log (from StackDriver "real" complement call):

```
{
   organizationId=XXXXXXXX, 
   fields=[
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=user_id, semantics={conceptType=DIMENSION, semanticType=NUMBER}}, 
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=tracked, semantics={isReaggregatable=true, conceptType=METRIC, semanticType=NUMBER}}, 
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=keyboard, semantics={isReaggregatable=true, conceptType=METRIC, semanticType=NUMBER}},
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=mouse, semantics={isReaggregatable=true, conceptType=METRIC, semanticType=NUMBER}},
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=overall, semantics={isReaggregatable=true, conceptType=METRIC, semanticType=NUMBER}}, 
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=idle, semantics={isReaggregatable=true, conceptType=METRIC, semanticType=NUMBER}}, 
      {dataType=NUMBER, name=resumed, semantics={isReaggregatable=true, conceptType=METRIC, semanticType=NUMBER}}
    ], 
    accessToken=XXXXXXXXX
}
```

The `"getData - rows"` log (from StackDriver "real" complement call):

```
[
   {values=[164079, 320317.0, 75110.0, 142879.0, 163043.0, 25266.0, 454.0]}, 
   {values=[642198, 301352.0, 73463.0, 135327.0, 154413.0, 24198.0, 0.0]}, 
   {values=[615157, 275512.0, 69592.0, 123441.0, 140382.0, 22181.0, 0.0]}, 
   {values=[741562, 258775.0, 66839.0, 115086.0, 130181.0, 22181.0, 0.0]}, 
   {values=[405833, 229674.0, 58363.0, 100779.0, 114785.0, 22181.0, 0.0]}
]
```

Comment: Do you get the issue for all `getData` requests for this connector or for this specific `getData` call with these fields only? (What happens if you make a bar chart with `user_id` and `user_id`?)

Comment: @MinhazKazi thank you for your comment. I think it was my fault. The stackdriver logging is not so intuitive tool and debugging on Google Script is not easy. The problem was another point. I answered my question. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but it's far away from what I expected.

I don't know exactly why, but, reading the logs I saw that they send the configuration params first time by `request.organizationId` and on next calls it send by `request.configParams.organizationId`. To handle this I did:

```
var organizatioInd = request.organizationId || request.configParams.organizationId;
var accessToken = request.accessToken || request.configParams.accessToken;
```

This is the only code I changed.

The log I past on my question, is the first call with right params, that log the right results. The second call (should be the real Studio call) ever failed because the wrong config.

Comment: It is a bit unlikely that `configParams` is sent once via `request` and then only via `request.configParams`. Is there any other place other than the 3rd line in `getData` where you are logging the `request` object?

Comment: I added a call to a one test method (for debug/testing purposes), and that method has a call to getData with that params (on root object). Then, when the Data Studio open the file to use the code the file itself calls the getData with wrong parameters, even before the Data Studio calls its... I'm new on GS and took a time to see that mistake.